# C++ modify Windows command line

Tags: c++

I have not touched a programming language since the days of Amos and qBasic. So I am getting back into it with c++.

I'm building a project I started back at college. A text adventure.

I have the basis of a semi working engine. But I am stuck on colouring and generally formatting the Windows Command Prompt.

Is it possible? And does anyone know a good tutorial for it?

Sorry for the noob question. I'm Just getting back into things and I'm enjoying myself :-)

Comment: you mean something like running `color2`? or `color3`?

Comment: So a portion of text like cont << "This would be bold blue"; would be lue on the black background of the Windows CMD Window.